# Conversion of 2-D matrix into 8 bit image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to convert a 2-d matrix into a 8 bit image using matlab ?

I have tried using mat2gray() but its returning a 1 bit image that is , only black and white

We also tried using im2uint8(H) to determine to get a 8bit image but is also not working for our case.

Then we tried using imwrite((H),'gray.jpg','Bitdepth',8);
But still we get only a 3-bit image with 7 gray scale values.Hence please suggest

Comment: How come `im2uint8` isn't working in your case?  `uint8` assumes that you will have **256** graylevel values, as 8 bits will generate 256 possible intensities.  What do you expect as an output?  I don't understand what you are expecting as the output when `im2uint8` should do the job for you.  Please describe your expected inputs and expected outputs.  It is impossible to determine this from your post.

Comment: What is your 2D matrix? is it an image data? Is the size of your matrix equal to your image dimension? If it is an image then my guess is it is a gray-scale image. I agree with above comment. In order to get accurate answer you need to give accurate information.